# Saving what is displayed in a leaflet popup

Tags: r, leaflet, polygon, spatial, r-sf

When I plot an address in leaflet, I can display the value in my dataset that corresponds to the row that the polygon is found on. But how can I save this value?

Example:

I plot an address in leaflet and have the popup display the median age in that neighbourhood. To my knowledge; there is no way to save this value.

I tried using raster and sf_intersection - to no avail - so I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this directly through leaflet.

Comment: Save the value to *where*? I'm pretty sure the user can manually copy-paste that into a text document.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment, I should have specified that I'm trying to automate this